# Debugging Error on Console Application using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vba, debugging, compiler-errors, console, visual-studio-2015

While trying to debug a simple Console Application with C# the following error message occurred:

> DNX SDK version not installed

I got a suggestion to upgrade Windows Powershell to 3.0 or higher. Nevertheless, I found my current Powershell Version is 3.0 and it still doesn't work.
I am using Windows 8 OS.

What else can I do?

Comment: I've created console applications with VS2015 on both 2012R2 and 10. So there is something in you project's set up that is causing it to try targeting DNX. Double check what framework version it is set to target.

Comment: Did you actually intend to create a console mode app that targets DNX?  Nothing particularly simple about it while it is in beta and changing rapidly.  Ensure you picked the right project template to get started, Visual C# > Windows > Classic Desktop > Console Application.

Comment: @Richard My VS2015 is targeted to Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Solution myself,you need a internet connection and visit the following website.. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1039152/DNX-SDK-Version-dnx-clr-win-x-beta-Failedto

First of all,you need to set the path in Environment Variables for Powershell
ie;C:\Windows\System32\Windows PowerShell\1.0
And then enter the following comments mentioned in the website..

Hope You guys find the solution 
Thank you